# JSON result cannot be parsed in PHP

Tags: php, json

Here is the JSON I am trying to parse:

```
{"results":[{"id":471033736,"url":"https://site.com/471033736.json","name":"Joe User","email":"xxxxx@someplace.com","created_at":"2013-09-16T16:34:23Z","updated_at":"2013-09-16T16:34:23Z","time_zone":"America/Los_Angeles","phone":null,"photo":null,"locale_id":null,"locale":"en-US","organization_id":20477117,"role":"end-user","verified":false,"split_testing_group_names":[],"external_id":null,"tags":[],"alias":null,"active":true,"shared":false,"shared_agent":false,"last_login_at":null,"signature":null,"details":null,"notes":null,"custom_role_id":null,"moderator":false,"ticket_restriction":"requested","only_private_comments":false,"restricted_agent":true,"suspended":false,"user_fields":{},"result_type":"user"}]}
```

The problem is when I try to parse this JSON in my curlWrap() method in PHP via the following:

```
  $data=curlWrap("/api/v2/search.json?page="."$page_count"."&query=type:user", null, "GET"))
  foreach ($data as $user_data){
  echo "This is: {$user_data}";
  echo "\n";
  }
```

prints the following (just seems to be the top level of the object):

> This is: Array
>
> This is:
>
> This is: https://example.com/v2/search.json?page=2&query=type%3Auser
>
> This is:
>
> This is: 605

which if I look at the JSON in the raw (browser) endpoint shows:

```
{
"results": [ … ],
"facets": null,
"next_page": "https://example.com/api/v2/search.json?page=2&query=type%3Auser",
"previous_page": null,
"count": 605
}
```

How would I get access to the 'results' data using PHP?

@ed-cotrell Here is output of the var_dump($data):

```
array(5) { ["results"]=> array(100) { [0]=> array(33) { ["id"]=> int(471033736) ["url"]=> string(61) "example/api/v2/users/471033736.json"; ["name"]=> string(13) "xxxx" ["result_type"]=> string(4) "user" } [1]=> . . } } ["facets"]=> NULL ["next_page"]=> string(77) "example/api/v2/search.json?page=2&query=type%3Auser"; ["previous_page"]=> NULL ["count"]=> int(605) }
```

@AbraCadaver - this is the output of print_r($data):

```
Array
(
[results] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 471033736
[url] => https://example.com/api/v2/users/471033736.json
[name] => Joe User
[email] => Joeuser@nowhere.comcom
[created_at] => 2013-09-16T16:34:23Z
[updated_at] => 2013-09-16T16:34:23Z
[time_zone] => America/Los_Angeles
(
 )

[result_type] => user
)

)

[facets] => 
[next_page] => https://site.com/api/v2/search.json?page=2&query=type%3Auser
[previous_page] => 
[count] => 605
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of PHP's built-in `json_decode` function for this:

```
 $data=curlWrap(...);
 $data = json_decode($data);
 var_dump($data);
```

should show you the internals of your JSON object. the JSON_DECODE function converts your JSON string to a standard PHP variable.

Comment: We both had similar thoughts. No reason to re-invent the wheel when you have native functions to deal with the problem.

Comment: Thank you, so the output of var_dump($data) is (snippet): array(5) { ["results"]=> array(100) { [0]=> array(33) { ["id"]=> int(471033736) ["url"]=> string(61) "xxxx/api/v2/users/471033736.json"; ["name"]=> string(13) "xxxx" ["result_type"]=> string(4) "user" } [1]=> . . } } ["facets"]=> NULL ["next_page"]=> string(77) "xxxx/api/v2/search.json?page=2&query=type%3Auser"; ["previous_page"]=> NULL ["count"]=> int(605) }




How would I access the internals of this JSON?

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you put in your function definition for your curlWrap function. But honestly I don't even use cURL anymore. Not with the advent of file_get_contents and it's ability to read from external sources (such as URLs).

You can even send custom headers, action types (POST, PUT, GET, etc), and everything you can do in cURL. It is just much easier to use.

Just do this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://api.mydomain.com/my-api-path/some_method/some_id';
$rawText = file_get_contents($url);
$responseObject = json_decode($rawText);
print_r($responseObject);
?>
```

Comment: Here is some recommended reading: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php and http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: :D I beat you by a few seconds but upvoting your answer as it is both more complete and I agree that using PHP's native file_get_contents is a better solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have also upvoted your solution. Either way one of us will have it and we both have good answers.

Answer (score 0):

`$data` just contains a string. You need to parse it:

```
$data = json_decode($data);
foreach ($data as $user_data) { // etc.
```

Comment: The output inside the foreach is as follows:
>>>
Array

https://xxxx/api/v2/search.json?page=2&query=type%3Auser

605
>>>>>

How would I parse this?

Comment: Do a print_r or var_dump instead of the foreach and edit your question with the output; it's very hard to analyze the output you have posted to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `curlWrap()` is already decoding the JSON.  The issue is that `$data` is an object and `results` is an object property that is an array.  You need to access `$data->results` as an array:

```
foreach($data->results as $result) {
    echo $result;
}
```

The object properties that are `null` are not strings they are actually `null` values so you won't see them.

Comment: Thank you - I tried this approach with foreach and data object. Unfortunately, nothing is returned/printed inside the loop referencing the results object property.

Comment: @user3093222: do a `print_r($data);` and edit with the output.